# Running SpringBoot Aplication (Ruoyi-Cloud) (Readme file is in Chinese)

Tags: spring-boot, docker, alibaba-cloud

I want to run [this](https://gitee.com/y_project/RuoYi-Cloud/) project using Intellij IDE. There are some docker files in the project but I don't know how to run docker files. When I try to run project it throws exeption. Following is the output of the run:

```
12:17:35.556 [main] INFO  c.a.n.c.c.i.LocalConfigInfoProcessor - [<clinit>,67] - LOCAL_SNAPSHOT_PATH:C:\Users\yusuf\nacos\config
12:17:35.559 [main] INFO  c.a.n.c.r.client - [lambda$createClient$0,77] - [RpcClientFactory] create a new rpc client of 5ab666dd-22bf-4774-b285-14179d238e72_config-0
12:17:35.622 [main] INFO  o.r.Reflections - [scan,232] - Reflections took 35 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 3 keys and 6 values 
12:17:35.648 [main] INFO  o.r.Reflections - [scan,232] - Reflections took 11 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 4 keys and 9 values 
12:17:35.659 [main] INFO  o.r.Reflections - [scan,232] - Reflections took 10 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 3 keys and 10 values 
12:17:35.751 [main] INFO  o.r.Reflections - [scan,232] - Reflections took 90 ms to scan 138 urls, producing 0 keys and 0 values 
12:17:35.763 [main] INFO  o.r.Reflections - [scan,232] - Reflections took 10 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 1 keys and 5 values 
12:17:35.776 [main] INFO  o.r.Reflections - [scan,232] - Reflections took 11 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 1 keys and 7 values 
12:17:35.787 [main] INFO  o.r.Reflections - [scan,232] - Reflections took 8 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 2 keys and 8 values 
12:17:35.860 [main] INFO  o.r.Reflections - [scan,232] - Reflections took 70 ms to scan 138 urls, producing 0 keys and 0 values 
12:17:35.861 [main] INFO  c.a.n.c.r.client - [printIfInfoEnabled,60] - [5ab666dd-22bf-4774-b285-14179d238e72_config-0]RpcClient init label, labels={module=config, Vipserver-Tag=null, source=sdk, Amory-Tag=null, Location-Tag=null, taskId=0, AppName=unknown}
12:17:35.861 [main] INFO  c.a.n.c.r.client - [printIfInfoEnabled,60] - [5ab666dd-22bf-4774-b285-14179d238e72_config-0]Register server push request handler:com.alibaba.nacos.client.config.impl.ClientWorker$ConfigRpcTransportClient$$Lambda$317/691779749
12:17:35.861 [main] INFO  c.a.n.c.r.client - [printIfInfoEnabled,60] - [5ab666dd-22bf-4774-b285-14179d238e72_config-0]Register server push request handler:com.alibaba.nacos.client.config.impl.ClientWorker$ConfigRpcTransportClient$$Lambda$318/37841489
12:17:35.862 [main] INFO  c.a.n.c.r.client - [printIfInfoEnabled,60] - [5ab666dd-22bf-4774-b285-14179d238e72_config-0]Registry connection listener to current client:com.alibaba.nacos.client.config.impl.ClientWorker$ConfigRpcTransportClient$1
12:17:35.862 [main] INFO  c.a.n.c.r.client - [printIfInfoEnabled,60] - [5ab666dd-22bf-4774-b285-14179d238e72_config-0]RpcClient init, ServerListFactory =com.alibaba.nacos.client.config.impl.ClientWorker$ConfigRpcTransportClient$2
12:17:35.869 [main] INFO  c.a.n.c.r.client - [printIfInfoEnabled,60] - [5ab666dd-22bf-4774-b285-14179d238e72_config-0] Try to connect to server on start up, server: {serverIp='127.0.0.1', server main port=8848}
12:17:38.910 [main] ERROR c.a.n.c.r.c.g.GrpcClient - [printIfErrorEnabled,99] - Server check fail, please check server 127.0.0.1 ,port 9848 is available , error ={}
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:566)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:445)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.common.remote.client.grpc.GrpcClient.serverCheck(GrpcClient.java:146)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.common.remote.client.grpc.GrpcClient.connectToServer(GrpcClient.java:268)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.common.remote.client.RpcClient.start(RpcClient.java:394)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.client.config.impl.ClientWorker$ConfigRpcTransportClient.ensureRpcClient(ClientWorker.java:941)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.client.config.impl.ClientWorker$ConfigRpcTransportClient.getOneRunningClient(ClientWorker.java:1104)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.client.config.impl.ClientWorker$ConfigRpcTransportClient.queryConfig(ClientWorker.java:996)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.client.config.impl.ClientWorker.getServerConfig(ClientWorker.java:407)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.client.config.NacosConfigService.getConfigInner(NacosConfigService.java:166)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.client.config.NacosConfigService.getConfig(NacosConfigService.java:94)
    at com.alibaba.cloud.nacos.client.NacosPropertySourceBuilder.loadNacosData(NacosPropertySourceBuilder.java:85)
    at com.alibaba.cloud.nacos.client.NacosPropertySourceBuilder.build(NacosPropertySourceBuilder.java:73)
    at com.alibaba.cloud.nacos.client.NacosPropertySourceLocator.loadNacosPropertySource(NacosPropertySourceLocator.java:199)
    at com.alibaba.cloud.nacos.client.NacosPropertySourceLocator.loadNacosDataIfPresent(NacosPropertySourceLocator.java:186)
    at com.alibaba.cloud.nacos.client.NacosPropertySourceLocator.loadNacosConfiguration(NacosPropertySourceLocator.java:158)
    at com.alibaba.cloud.nacos.client.NacosPropertySourceLocator.loadSharedConfiguration(NacosPropertySourceLocator.java:116)
    at com.alibaba.cloud.nacos.client.NacosPropertySourceLocator.locate(NacosPropertySourceLocator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceLocator.locateCollection(PropertySourceLocator.java:51)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceLocator.locateCollection(PropertySourceLocator.java:47)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:634)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:403)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:337)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
    at com.ruoyi.modules.monitor.RuoYiMonitorApplication.main(RuoYiMonitorApplication.java:18)
Caused by: com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
    at com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:490)
```

I cloned project and try to run with sdk 1.8. But it dosen't work. What steps should I follow to run the project?

Comment: Is docker installed and running in your system?

Comment: Which command line are you typing to get this result ?

Comment: you should have nacos server version 2+ and also I think you solve this question kindly write the answer.

Comment: I found the solution. For runing project without docker use following guide:
https://programmerall.com/article/49212236774/
I was trying to run project with docker. I defined problem and the solution in official gittee project:
https://gitee.com/y_project/RuoYi-Cloud/issues/I4OEVY#note_8800779